# How to put code into another macro to avoid duplication?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, tex-core, xparse

The following code has two branches: If true-branch, argument #2 is put into `\colorbox` by which is typeset; If false-branch, argument #2 is typeset directly.

#2 has to appear in both branches. In the first part of my example(`\cmda`), the code of #2 is simple(just itself). But if the code of #2 is large and complex, it will be boring to duplicate the part of #2 code.

Then I tried with the second part of my example(`\cmdb`) by `bgroup` and `egroup`, but failed.

So, how to "cap" a part of code with another macro, as I tried in `\cmdb`?

**EXAMPLE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,xparse,xcolor}
\geometry{showframe}


\begin{document}
%%%%% \cmda %%%%%
\NewDocumentCommand\cmda{sm}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}
{\colorbox{green}{#2}}
{#2}
}

Test: \par
\cmda*{with back-ground color.} \cmda{no back-ground color.}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%% \cmdb %%%%%
\NewDocumentCommand\cmdb{sm}{%
\IfBooleanT{#1}
{\colorbox{green}\bgroup}
#2
\IfBooleanT{#1}{\egroup}
}

Test: \par
\cmdb*{with back-ground color.} \cmdb{no back-ground color.}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\colorbox` wraps things into something like an `\fbox` whose frame-lines have a thickness of 0pt and wherein the background of things is colored.

Seems with star you wish this box with background-coloring while without star you don't wish any wrapping into a box at all.

This way measurements of things differ depending on whether coloring the background is desired or not.

You can use the kernel-macro `\@firstofone`.

If you don't want to wrap things between `\makeatletter..\makeatother` you can do `\csname @firstofone\endcsname`.

In expl3-syntax `\@firstofone` is `\use:n`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,xparse,xcolor}
\geometry{showframe}


%%%%% \cmda %%%%%
\NewDocumentCommand\cmda{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
              {\colorbox{green}}%
              {\csname @firstofone\endcsname}%
              {#2}%
}

\begin{document}
Test: \par
\cmda*{with back-ground color.} \cmda{no back-ground color.}
\end{document}
```

If you wish the same measurements both for the colored and the uncolored boxes, s.th. like this might do the trick:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,xparse,xcolor}
\geometry{showframe}


%%%%% \cmda %%%%%

\newcommand\framelessfbox[1]{{\fboxrule=0pt \fbox{#1}}}%
\NewDocumentCommand\cmda{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
              {\colorbox{green}}%
              {\framelessfbox}%
              {#2}%
}

\begin{document}
Test: \par
\fbox{\cmda*{with or without back-ground color.}} \fbox{\cmda{with or without back-ground color.}}

\fbox{\cmda{with or without back-ground color.}} \fbox{\cmda*{with or without back-ground color.}}
\end{document}
```

[image]